# Variables and string concatenation inside jQuery selectors - is it considered harmful?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, string-concatenation

I often see string concatenation inside jQuery selectors:

```
var $field = $('.' + field, $form);
var $label = $('label[for="' + $field.attr('id') + '"]');
var $elem = $('#' + elem);
```

Since [periods and colons are valid in element ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) (and who knows what might be in other attributes), is code like this not potentially dangerous?

I have found that some selectors aren't trivial to write in any other way - so what is the standard practice? Native DOM methods are not always available.

I have always avoided weird characters in ids and the like, but when writing tools for general use by others it would be nice to avoid that caveat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have full control over the content in the string, then it's not a problem, but for a library tool it would be a problem.

Simply don't accept a name or identity for the tool, accept a complete selector or an element/jQuery reference. That way it's the responsibility of the person using the tool to create a working selector.

Comment: I like that idea. In my particular tool though, I have a list of names and ids of form fields specified server-side which are used again when the form is posted back (required fields for example). Specifying `['name1','name2','name3']` server-side is simply the easiest option for the user, and then my code handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and third examples are common, and harmless so long as you control what's in `field` and `elem`.

I never use the second form, and would write it like so:

```
var match = $field.attr('id');      // or $field[0].id
var $label = $('label').filter(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('for') === match;
});
```

thus completely avoiding the need to worry about escaping the contents of `match`.

Comment: But isn't this way more expensive - since it won't use the browser's native `querySelector` or similar?

Comment: @Andrew it's _potentially_ (slightly) more expensive, depending on just how many `label` elements there are.  I wouldn't worry about the difference unless this call was being made repeatedly in a tight loop.

Comment: Thanks - why would you never use the second if the first and third are OK?

Comment: @Andrew consistency of style, I guess.  It's the need to worry about quoting levels that tips that one over the edge for me.